# Formatter in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use `Formatter` by using Android Studio as documentation from https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter

However, in my code the `Formatter` does not allow any argument:

When I try to use this:

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
```

it says that expected 0 arguments found 2.

Also,

```
formatter.format(argments)
```

format is also not supported. It says cannot resolve **format** in **Formatter**
Please help in this regard.

Comment: Have you checked the import?

Comment: Do I need to add any import if I use Formatter as 
this line gives no error i.e here I put no arguments in formatter.
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();

Only when I specify arguments I get error and .format is also not supported. I am getting no solutions to resolve this on internet.

Answer (score 0):

You must add StringBuilder first. Also in the format must be a format to define the order.
You must add StringBuilder first. Also in the format must be a format to define the order

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Send all output to the Appendable object sb Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US); // Explicit argument indices may be used to re-order output. formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c",` "d")

Comment: I already did this ie I added the String Builder like you have but that's what in my case when I type the second line:
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
I get the error that "it says that expected 0 arguments found 2"
and then formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
gives error that "It says cannot resolve format in Formatter"